# change element value into other symbols

Tags: javascript

Good day everyone,

i am trying to change value of each element inside body by using pure js without any framework.

for example, you open console insert js and it changes all the values in each element of body into other symbols.

So basically i can get all the visible words on the website for user without any html markdowns.

like:

```
<li>This is text</li> 

t->p
h->s
i->e
s->l
e->o
x->z
```

will be

```
<li>Psel el pozp</li>
```

so, don't know how to loop through each elements value.
this is what i tried

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
   if (elems[i].innerHTML.indexOf('<script') != -1){
       console.log(elems[i]);
   } else {
       continue;
   }
}

function validate(element){
    if(element.indexOf('<div') == -1){
        return false;
    } else if(element.indexOf('<script') == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but cannot get it to work.

**updated:**
i think it is my bad. i didnt say that i need to change the values on fly. i mean if i insert the code in console, it should loop through each element, get it value, change values by replacing each letter into another letter, then put the value back instead of the old one. eventually it looks on the web different. thank you in advance.

so i need the code **to loop through each element, get its value**, do something with it and then **put it back.**
in bold is what i cannot do. thank you to everyone in advance.

Comment: `indexOf('<div')` ? I see no `div` here in the html.  Please update your question to add a good deal more clarity

Comment: I understand the final goal. But what do u expect ur code to do that is not doing? U just want it to log some elements to the console. Does it not do that?

Also what is the purpose of `validate` function here? Why is it not being used?

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has to do with anything you have described as your objective. Using either `function validate()` nor the `for` loop comes even close to getting a result of : `<li>Psel el pozp</li>`

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss
yes, because if choose any web site, all the web will have at list one div and script i suppose. and this code is not for html but for js. many thanks :-)

Comment: @Amiratak88  
well, i described what i need. the rest code is working. if i post the whole code it will be a long list but why do that if the rest code is working right. the question is. how to loop through each element of the body and get it value so i can change letters into other letters. validate function s purpose. i thought that when i use innerHTML and loop through the array it returns sometimes not the value but with tags. **continued in the next comment**

Comment: @zer00ne
**beginning in the previous comment**
like array[1]->'<li>something</li>. array[2]->something. so basically i dont need array[1] i need array[2]'. so i thought i may exclude it by writing validate function. then it turned out that my js knowledge is quite bad and i actually get an object instead of a string. then i decided to ask for help from professionals. thank you in advance and sorry if i confused you in the first place.

Comment: @Marat Ok see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55325421/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

First, in your `for` loop, add the call to `validate`. Then in `validate`, add the text replacement:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
   if (elems[i].innerHTML.indexOf('<script') != -1){
       console.log(elems[i]);
   } else {
       validate(elems[i]);
   }
}

function validate(element){
    if(element.indexOf('<div') == -1){
        return false;
    } else if(element.indexOf('<script') == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        element.innerText = element.innerText.replace("t", "p"); //Add the others as well
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i already have a code that substitutes it. i use regular expression. can you help me loop through the elements from body so i can get all the actual values from each element in the body. like value from p, a, li etc. so basically i can get all the visible words on the website for user without any html markdowns. many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) & [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

> *"So basically I can get all the visible words on the website for user without any HTML markdown."* <sup>✱</sup>
> <sup><sup>✱</sup>Upper case and grammatical corrections are mine</sup>

Text can be extracted from HTML easily just by using `.textContent` or `.innerText` properties. There are some significant differences between results and minor inconsistency of standards, see links above and demo below.

---

### Demo

**Run the demo and click the `Results` link or scroll to the very bottom**

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');

var tC = document.getElementById('textContent');
tC.textContent = content.textContent;

var iT = document.getElementById('innerText');
iT.innerText = content.innerText;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='content' class='container'>
    <header id='top' class='container'>
      <hgroup class='row'>
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </hgroup>
      <nav class='row'>
        <ul class='nav col-12'>
          <li class='p-2'><a href='#a0'>Section 1</a></li>
          <li class='p-2'><a href='#a1'>Section 2</a></li>
          <li class='p-2'><a href='#a2'>Section 3</a></li>
          <li class='p-2'><a href='#a3'>Article</a></li>
          <li class='p-2'><a href='#a4'>Results</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <main class='container'>
      <section id='a0' class='row'>
        <article class='col-12'>
          <h2>Section I</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos nonumy omittam ex. No dicant tibique accusamus pri, sed omnis posidonium ad. In sea dico honestatis, ex repudiare reprimique delicatissimi mea. Sit dicta moderatius ad, natum convenire usu ei. Est no graece laboramus
            deterruisset. </p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section id='a1' class='row'>
        <article class='col-12'>
          <h2>Section II</h2>
          <p>Mundi nemore iisque in nec. An dolorum intellegat conclusionemque eos, ad labore omittam mel. Te nam wisi omittam patrioque, oporteat honestatis intellegebat cu mei. Odio cibo omittantur te sed.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section id='a2' class='row'>
        <article class='col-12'>
          <h2>Section III</h2>
          <p>Alii commodo ne sea, eu pro legimus signiferumque. At mei nisl facete adolescens, et mel eleifend voluptatibus. Qui ei wisi sonet noster, est solum posidonium scribentur et, sea nobis verear ut. Nemore admodum usu ne.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <hr>
      <section id='a3' class='row'>
        <article class='col-12'>
          <h2>Article</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quot erroribus voluptatum in pri. Fabulas vocibus insolens his ex. Vide laboramus ius et, at sit adhuc doctus luptatum, et sit dicat inani democritum. His liber blandit pericula id, an fugit reformidans neglegentur
            cum. Indoctum intellegat et pro, sed fabulas ocurreret eu. Nam ut fabulas inciderint, iracundia conceptam ne vix, quo offendit inimicus torquatos in.</p>
          <div class='row'>
            <aside class='col-4 float-left'>
              <blockquote>
                <p>Duo illum assum discere ne, sed cu posse alterum accusam. Cum an error pertinacia, aperiam deleniti</p>
              </blockquote>
            </aside>
            <p class='col-8'>Ut has elit labores, ex animal delectus efficiendi eos. Id soleat accusamus mel, sint deterruisset his an. Civibus fabellas interpretaris vis ea, dicat aperiri nec ut. Et posidonium dissentias ius, essent quodsi no nam. Mei graece prompta
              quaestio et, pri no voluptua atomorum. Pri id putant graecis. Autem prompta nostrud ut mei, mea ut facilisis expetenda intellegebat.</p>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <p class='col-12'>Quo dolor commune albucius ea, ad novum senserit mediocritatem pro, te nisl quidam intellegam nam. Audire omittam in sea, per veniam noster ne. Duo illum assum discere ne, sed cu posse alterum accusam. Cum an error pertinacia, aperiam deleniti
              sedcu. Pri ut facilisi hendrerit reformidans, id qui modus libris deseruisse, cum primis moderatius ut.</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
    </main>
    <hr>
    <footer class='container'>
      <nav class='row'>
        <ul class='nav col-12'>
          <li><a href='#top'>HOME</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--End of #content-->
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <section id='a4' class='container'>
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <h3><code>textContent</code></h3>
        <div id='textContent' class='col-10'></div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class='row'>
        <h3><code>innerText</code></h3>
        <div id='innerText' class='col-10'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, it works but. i think it is my bad. i didnt say that i need to change the values on fly. i mean if i insert the code in console, it should loop through each element, get it value, change values by replacing each letter into another letter, then put the value back instead of the old one. eventually it looks on the web different. thank you in advance.

Comment: @Marat How is it changed? What is the pattern? If x = z how is e = o?  Can't help if the pattern isn't known, I don't answer with incomplete code.

Comment: the question is how to loop through each element, get its value, and put the value back. i ll handle the intermediate code. just please help with this. it doesnt matter how it is replaced just let me know please how to loop get the value and put the value back. many thanks from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: JavaScript is loosely typed meaning that writing code for whatever data is thrown in is a guessing game. How do I know what your mystery code has side effects or results are not what's expected? You might not realize your code mangles the rest of the code and then you'll say "It doesn't work". That's a waste of time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as you have posted does not call the `validate` function so I will totally ignore that.  Your stated objective is really not super clear however I will put an attempt to loop through some elements with something similar to what you have.

For my code, I add a class to everything that is not skipped; that is where you would do your processing; call your function etc. i.e. `el.classList.add("show-processors");`

Note:`skipList` an the function `filterBySkipCheck` are the key parts here.

```js
function doSomething(el) {
  const showplace = document.getElementById('actions-display')
    .getElementsByClassName('showme')[0];
  showplace.innerText = showplace.innerText + el.innerText;
  const textContentOutput = document.getElementById('textContentOutput');
  const innerTextOutput = document.getElementById('innerTextOutput');
  textContentOutput.innerHTML = el.textContent;
  innerTextOutput.innerHTML = el.innerText;
}

function hasParentWithMatchingSelector(target, selector) {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].some(el =>
    el !== target && el.contains(target)
  );
}

function hasMatchingSelector(target, selector) {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].some(el =>
    el === target
  );
}

function hasClass(element, classname) {
  return element.classList.contains(classname);;
}

function hasSelfOrParentWithClass(element, classname) {
  if (element.classList.contains(classname)) return true;
  return element.parentNode && hasSelfOrParentWithClass(element.parentNode, classname);
}

function hasParentWithClass(element, classname) {
  return hasParentWithMatchingSelector(element, '.' + classname);
}

function filterBySkipCheck(el, index, myarr, skipList) {
  let isSkipped = false;
  // process each item in skip list
  skipList.forEach(function(skip) {
    if (!isSkipped && skip.matchType === 'tag') {
      isSkipped = el.tagName === skip.match;
    }
    if (!isSkipped && skip.matchType === 'skipclass') {
      isSkipped = hasClass(el, skip.match);
    }
    if (!isSkipped && skip.matchType === 'selector') {
      isSkipped = hasMatchingSelector(el, skip.match);
    }
    if (!isSkipped && skip.matchType === 'parentselector') {
      isSkipped = hasParentWithMatchingSelector(el, skip.match);
    }
    if (!isSkipped && skip.matchType === 'element') {
      isSkipped = el === skip.match;
    }
  });
  return isSkipped;
}

function processAllElements(elements, skipL) {

  // filter for stuff to skip
  const filteredElements = [...elements].filter(function(el, index, myarr) {
    return filterBySkipCheck(el, index, myarr, skipL);
  });
  // this answers the question, how to process/loop through all but also how to filter
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
    let el = elements[i];
    let isSkipped = filteredElements.includes(elements[i]);
    let shouldProcess = !isSkipped;
    if (shouldProcess) {
      el.classList.add("show-processors");
    }
  }
}

let skipList = [{
  match: "SECTION",
  matchType: "tag"
}, {
  match: "SCRIPT",
  matchType: "tag"
}, {
  match: "STYLE",
  matchType: "tag"
}, {
  match: "skipme-also",
  matchType: "skipclass"
}, {
  match: ".skipme",
  matchType: "selector"
}, {
  match: ".skipme",
  matchType: "parentselector"
}, {
  match: document.getElementById('second-skip'),
  matchType: "element"
}];

let elementsInScope = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
processAllElements(elementsInScope, skipList);
```

```css
.show-processors {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.show-skippers {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var myfriend = "pluto";
</script>
<div>first</div>
<div id='second-skip'>second</div>
<div>nested one
  <div>nested inner
    <div>nested granchild</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>container for list
  <ul>in the list
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div><a href="#">testlink</a>
  <button type="button">button</button>
  <span>span1</span><span>spanner2</span>
</div>
<section>test section to skip</section>

<div class="skipme-also">I am skipped</div>
<div class="skipme">skip me by class</div>
<div>I contain paragraphs
  <p>Happy day</p>
  <p>Happy day2</p>
  <p>Happy day3</p>after paragraphs
</div>
<div id="actions-display" class="skipme">I just show stuff
  <button id="test-button" type="text">Click to test</button>
  <div class="showme"></div>
  <h3>Result of textContent:</h3>
  <textarea id="textContentOutput" rows="6" cols="30" readonly>...</textarea>
  <h3>Result of innerText:</h3>
  <textarea id="innerTextOutput" rows="6" cols="30" readonly>...</textarea> JavaScript
</div>
```